# Generate table body rows using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, smart-table

I'm using Smart Table (latest version) and AngularJs (v. 1.2.16) to build a table using two objects, one for the header and the other for the table content. My problem happens when creating the table body cells. Using the following code works fine:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
    <td>{{row.productNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{row.BuyIt}}</td>
    <td>{{row.brand}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I need to generate the body like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
    <td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{value-to-show}}</td>
</tr>
```

My object is this:

```
$scope.rowCollection = [{
    "productNumber": 5877,
    "BuyIt": "Online",
    "brand": "BrandA"
}, {
    "productNumber": 5743,
    "BuyIt": "Online",
    "brand": "BrandB"
}];

$scope.columns = [{
    'colName': 'Product Number',
    'Id': 'column1',
    'className': '',
    'skipNatural': true,
    'sortDefault': 'reverse'
}, {
    'colName': 'Store or Online',
    'Id': 'column2',
    'className': '',
    'skipNatural': true
}, {
    'colName': 'Brand',
    'Id': 'column3',
    'className': '',
    'skipNatural': true
}];
```

How can I get the right value to appear in the right cell?

I have a jsfiddle that shows the problem: h[ttp://plnkr.co/edit/aEfzzU?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/aEfzzU?p=preview)

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand why you need to iterate columns inside of rows. Can you explain why the first solution you posted isn't adequate for what you want to do?

Comment: I found a plunker using smart-table and angularjs that generates the rows the way I wanted: http://plnkr.co/edit/DRagFo?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can change your ng-repeat to this:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: It loads the data but does not respect the order. See my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aEfzzU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You may also extend your column objects with which property it corresponds with like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
  <td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{row[col.property]}}</td>
</tr>
```

This will also have the nice side effects of:

- You may in your header use the st-sort directive on col.property to enable sorting
- Dynamically change which columns to display
- Use your column objects as a configuration for both header and body
- Use on complex objects which contains more properties than you care to show!